# How to selectively disable editing in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

By default editing is activated by F2, double click and typing in selected cell.
How can I enable/disable these (some of them) editting triggers?

Comment: An example of a trigger you want to enable or disable?

Comment: @Blam. I want editing only by F2 or double click but not typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datagrid.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(datagrid_KeyDown);

void datagrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //obviously you'll have to add some code here
        //if(!datagridIsInEditMode) then
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F2))
                   datagrid.BeginEdit();
            else
                  e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try. The deeper I delve into DataGrid the more I get disapointed. Event IsInEditMode property is not implemented out of the box. =(

Comment: I am going to post another suggestion" in a few min

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way is to leave datagrid's behavior alone, it knows what it's doing, and create your own control in the edting template. Lets call it (for reference) CustomTextBox. Have that CustomTextBox do what you like, such as responding to F2 key only, etc. That way you are not creating weird behaviors in the datagrid, and encapsulating custom behaviors in your custom control.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <yourNamespace:CustomTextBox DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It seems to me tata templates are switched when mode is changed. So I need the way to tell DataGrid when it'd be done.